# Understanding the assembly dump of the following program

Tags: c, memory, x86, arguments

i have written a c program for printing the arguments

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
printf("argument %d=%s\n",i,argv[i]);
}
```

The assembly dump for the above program using gdb i got is.

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x00000000004004f4 <+0>:    push   %rbp
0x00000000004004f5 <+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x00000000004004f8 <+4>:    sub    $0x20,%rsp
0x00000000004004fc <+8>:    mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
0x00000000004004ff <+11>:   mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
0x0000000000400503 <+15>:   movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
0x000000000040050a <+22>:   movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
0x0000000000400511 <+29>:   jmp    0x40053e <main+74>
0x0000000000400513 <+31>:   mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
0x0000000000400516 <+34>:   cltq   
0x0000000000400518 <+36>:   shl    $0x3,%rax
0x000000000040051c <+40>:   add    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
0x0000000000400520 <+44>:   mov    (%rax),%rdx
0x0000000000400523 <+47>:   mov    $0x40063c,%eax
0x0000000000400528 <+52>:   mov    -0x4(%rbp),%ecx
0x000000000040052b <+55>:   mov    %ecx,%esi
0x000000000040052d <+57>:   mov    %rax,%rdi
0x0000000000400530 <+60>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x0000000000400535 <+65>:   callq  0x4003f0 <printf@plt>
0x000000000040053a <+70>:   addl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
0x000000000040053e <+74>:   mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
0x0000000000400541 <+77>:   cmp    -0x14(%rbp),%eax
0x0000000000400544 <+80>:   jl     0x400513 <main+31>
0x0000000000400546 <+82>:   leaveq 
0x0000000000400547 <+83>:   retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

Now what i want is " The memory locations (addresses) at which the argument is passing.
for eg if i run the program as " arg 1"
it prints the arguments.
Now I want to know on which instruction it is extracting this argument ,or which register holds the arguments (also take the case if i pass more than 1 argument.. (will this tell me the memory address on which it resides?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know on which instruction it is extracting this argument ,or
>   which register holds the arguments

This sort of question is best answered by obtaining an assembly language reference manual for the target machine and studying it. However, your specific questions are easily answered by examination without being very familiar with the specifics of the assembly language:

```
0x0000000000400503 <+15>:   movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
0x000000000040050a <+22>:   movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
```

This is the code generated for the redundant `i = 0` statements.

```
0x0000000000400513 <+31>:   mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
```

The value of `i` is now in the %eax register.

```
0x0000000000400518 <+36>:   shl    $0x3,%rax
0x000000000040051c <+40>:   add    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
```

This calculates the address of `argv[i]` and puts it in the %rax register.

```
0x0000000000400520 <+44>:   mov    (%rax),%rdx
```

This loads the value of `argv[i]` into the %rdx register. Code following calls `printf` with `i` and `argv[i]` as arguments.

> Now what i want is " The memory locations (addresses) at which the
>   argument is passing.

You can no more determine that by looking at the asm than you can determine the value of argc by looking at the asm ... these are values that vary and are only determined when actually **running** the program. If you want to determine the address at runtime, you could use

```
printf("address of argv = %p\n", (void*)argv);
```

If that's what you want, then dumping asm and learning what it means is unnecessary and not relevant to your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `gdb` to debug, I guess you might use Linux. Then, use `gcc -S -Wall -fverbose-asm foo.c` (possibly with optimization flags like `-O2`) to get a more understandable `foo.s` assembly file, assuming your file is `foo.c` (if it is `hello.c` replace `foo` by `hello`). Then look inside `foo.s` with an editor (like `gedit` or `emacs`).

And `main` is almost an ordinary function (except its signature has to be what is permitted by the standard, e.g. `int main(int argc, char**argv)` ....) and it is called by `crt0.o` (compile with `gcc -v` to learn which one).

You might want to read the [Linux Assembly Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/) and e.g. the [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) and the [x86 calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) wikipage.

Notice that without any optimization flags (e.g. `-O1` or `-O2`) the `gcc` compiler generates very naive code.

Comment: it generates a warning, warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]

Comment: Yes, because `main` should return an `int` and accept two arguments, e.g. be `int main (int argc, char**argv)` .... And you should compile with `-Wall` and improve your code till no warnings are given.

Comment: and after that use the same command in gdb ,i used disas /m main

Comment: can you tell me by looking at the dump , at which address the arguments reside ?

Comment: i am a noob ! can you tell me where to put the flags

Comment: I suggest you to follow my answer: compile with `gcc -fverbose-asm -S -O`, read all the references. the `argv` array is the second argument to `main`.

Comment: alrite i compiled using wht u wrote ! now how should i dump it using gdb ? if i use disas /m main .its giving the same result

Comment: No, after compiling with `gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O foo.c` you should look inside the produced `foo.s` assembly file with some editor, e.g. run `gedit foo.s` or `emacs foo.s`; you don't need `gdb`, just to look into the generated assembly file `foo.s`

Comment: @archies50 No, the asm cannot show you the address at which the arguments reside ... you need to **run** the program to determine that.